# What is the difference between RMA and RMA authorization?

Tags: magento-enterprise, rma

I know what is RMA and what does it stand for but I don't know whats the **difference between RMA and RMA authorization**. Searched on Google as well as Magento Knowledge Base but did not find anything that I was looking for. To be specific it's available under **Sales Email->RMA** and **Sales Email->RMA Authorization** in **Magento Enterprise Edition**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"RMA Authorization" field is needed for sending emails when RMA is authorised by Admin user, means items are eligible to be returned. Admin user will be able to create shipping label after that.